# Migration problem after copy table, how to copy also indices and foreignKeys?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-migration, android-room

I need to delete some columns from very large roomDB(SQLite) table.

From what I've read, I can't delete columns from an existing table , To do so I need to create a new table and copy the desired columns (except those we want to delete)

I manage to delete those columns well by copying to a new table, but migration doesn't work because **foreignKeys**  and **indices** arae missing, what is the clean syntax to do that?

this is the method that i use in the migration to delete some columns:

```
 private static void deleteColumns(SupportSQLiteDatabase database, String tableName, List<String> columnsToRemove){
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> columnNamesWithType = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> primaryKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "pragma table_info(" + tableName + ");";

    Cursor cursor = database.query(query);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String columnName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));

        if (columnsToRemove.contains(columnName)){
            continue;
        }

        String columnType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        boolean isNotNull = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("notnull")) == 1;
        boolean isPk = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pk")) == 1;

        columnNames.add(columnName);
        String tmp = "`" + columnName + "` " + columnType + " ";
        if (isNotNull){
            tmp += " NOT NULL ";
        }

        int defaultValueType = cursor.getType(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value"));
        if (defaultValueType == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING){
            tmp += " DEFAULT " + "\"" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value")) + "\" ";
        }else if(defaultValueType == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER){
            tmp += " DEFAULT " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value")) + " ";
        }else if (defaultValueType == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT){
            tmp += " DEFAULT " + cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value")) + " ";
        }
        columnNamesWithType.add(tmp);
        if (isPk){
            primaryKeys.add("`" + columnName + "`");
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

    String columnNamesSeparated = TextUtils.join(", ", columnNames);
    if (primaryKeys.size() > 0){
        columnNamesWithType.add("PRIMARY KEY("+ TextUtils.join(", ", primaryKeys) +")");
    }
    String columnNamesWithTypeSeparated = TextUtils.join(", ", columnNamesWithType);

    database.beginTransaction();
    try {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " RENAME TO " + tableName + "_old;");
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (" + columnNamesWithTypeSeparated + ") + FOREIGN KEY +(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid) ;" );
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columnNamesSeparated + ") SELECT "
                + columnNamesSeparated + " FROM " + tableName + "_old;");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + tableName + "_old;");
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }finally {
        database.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the before and after schema (the entities and the create table statements used in the migration). In short the altered tables have to match the schema that the entity(s) will generate.

Comment: Thank you, 
I updated as you requested, I know that  altered tables have  to match the schema , the error happens because I can't copy  foreignKeys and indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't copy foreignKeys and indices

For **Foreign Keys** you can base the generation of them on the output from [**`PRAGMA foreign_keys_list(the_table)`**](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list) which produces output such as :-

[image]

For **indicies** you can base the generation of them on the output from [**`PRAGMA index_list(the_table)`**](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_list) to get the index names and check for the UNIQUE constraint.

[image]

With the index name you can then use [**`PRAGMA index_info(the_index_name)`**](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_info)

[image]

For example the following adaptation of your code will work (COMMENTS in regards to limitations) :-

```
private static void deleteColumns(SupportSQLiteDatabase database, String tableName, List<String> columnsToRemove){
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> columnNamesWithType = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> primaryKeys = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "pragma table_info(" + tableName + ");";
    Cursor cursor = database.query(query);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String columnName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));

        if (columnsToRemove.contains(columnName)){
            continue;
        }

        String columnType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
        boolean isNotNull = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("notnull")) == 1;
        boolean isPk = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pk")) == 1;

        columnNames.add(columnName);
        String tmp = "`" + columnName + "` " + columnType + " ";
        if (isNotNull){
            tmp += " NOT NULL ";
        }

        int defaultValueType = cursor.getType(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value"));
        if (defaultValueType == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING){
            tmp += " DEFAULT " + "\"" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value")) + "\" ";
        }else if(defaultValueType == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER){
            tmp += " DEFAULT " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value")) + " ";
        }else if (defaultValueType == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT){
            tmp += " DEFAULT " + cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("dflt_value")) + " ";
        }
        columnNamesWithType.add(tmp);
        if (isPk){
            primaryKeys.add("`" + columnName + "`");
        }
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< GET THE FOREIGN KEYS SQL FOR THE TABLE >>>>>>>>>>
    //!!!!!WARNING!!!!! DOES NOT ENCLOSE COLUMN NAMES AS THE COULD BE CSV LIST of columns
    //                  (should split and enclose them)
    //!!!!!WARNING!!!!! As information gathered is from the ORIGINAL table there may be issues
    //                  columns are skipped
    cursor = database.query("PRAGMA foreign_key_list(" + tableName + ");");
    StringBuilder foreignKeySQL = new StringBuilder();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (isColumnToBeRemoved(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("from")),columnsToRemove)) {
            continue;
        }
        foreignKeySQL.append(",FOREIGN KEY (")
                .append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("from")))
                .append(") REFERENCES `")
                .append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("table")))
                .append("`(")
                .append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("to")))
                .append(") ")
                .append(" ON DELETE ")
                .append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("on_delete")))
                .append(" ON UPDATE ").append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("on_update")))
        ;
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< GET THE INDICES CREATE SQL as an ArrayList<string> >>>>>>>>>>
    //!!!!!WARNING As information gathered is from the ORIGINAL table there may be issues
    ArrayList<String> indicesSQL = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = database.query("PRAGMA index_list(" + tableName + ")");
    //Cursor cursor2;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        boolean includesRemovedColumn = false;
        String unique = "";
        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("unique")) > 0) {
            unique = " UNIQUE ";
        }
        StringBuilder currentIndex = new StringBuilder().append("CREATE " + unique + " INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `")
                .append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")))
                .append("` ON `").append(tableName).append("`(");
        Cursor cursor2 = database.query("PRAGMA index_info(" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")) + ")");
        boolean afterFirst = false;
        while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
            if (isColumnToBeRemoved(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("name")),columnsToRemove)) {
                includesRemovedColumn = true;
            }
            if (afterFirst) {
                currentIndex.append(",");
            }
            afterFirst = true;
            currentIndex.append("`")
                    .append(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("name"))).append("`");
        }
        cursor2.close();
        currentIndex.append(");");
        if (!includesRemovedColumn) {
            indicesSQL.add(currentIndex.toString());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();


    String columnNamesSeparated = TextUtils.join(", ", columnNames);
    if (primaryKeys.size() > 0){
        columnNamesWithType.add("PRIMARY KEY("+ TextUtils.join(", ", primaryKeys) +")");
    }
    String columnNamesWithTypeSeparated = TextUtils.join(", ", columnNamesWithType);

    //<<<<<<<<<< FOR LOGGING/ CHECKING >>>>>>>>>
    String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (" + columnNamesWithTypeSeparated + foreignKeySQL + ")";
    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columnNamesSeparated + ") SELECT "
            + columnNamesSeparated + " FROM " + tableName + "_old;";
    String alterTableSQL = "ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " RENAME TO " + tableName + "_old;";
    String dropTableSQL = "DROP TABLE " + tableName + "_old;";
    Log.d("ALTERSQL",alterTableSQL);
    Log.d("CREATESQL",createTableSQL);
    Log.d("INSERTSQL",insertSQL);
    Log.d("DROPSQL",dropTableSQL);
    for (String ixsql: indicesSQL) {
        Log.d("CREATEINDEXSQL",ixsql);
    }
    database.beginTransaction();
    try {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " RENAME TO " + tableName + "_old;");
        //database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (" + columnNamesWithTypeSeparated + ") + FOREIGN KEY +(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid) ;" );
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (" + columnNamesWithTypeSeparated + foreignKeySQL + ")" );
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columnNamesSeparated + ") SELECT "
                + columnNamesSeparated + " FROM " + tableName + "_old;");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + tableName + "_old;");
        for (String ixsql: indicesSQL) {
            database.execSQL(ixsql);
        }
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }finally {
        database.endTransaction();
    }
}

//<<<<<<<<<< FOR CHECKING IF COLUMN EXISTS >>>>>>>>>>
private static boolean isColumnToBeRemoved(String column, List<String> columnsToRemove) {
    for (String s: columnsToRemove) {
        if (s.toLowerCase().equals(column.toLowerCase())) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

An alternative approach, which may be simpler than trying to cater for all the permutations would be to

- a) change the Entitities and then
- b) grab the SQL from the generated code from the @Database's _impl. e.g. The above was successfully tested on a simple 1 column removal,with 2 FK's and an index covering both mapped columns, grabbing the following could have bee used

:-

```
  public void createAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `device_item` (`id` INTEGER, `initial` TEXT, `added1` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `added2` TEXT DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (`id` INTEGER, `name` TEXT, `mapToTable2` INTEGER NOT NULL, `mapToTable3` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`), FOREIGN KEY(`mapToTable2`) REFERENCES `table2`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION , FOREIGN KEY(`mapToTable3`) REFERENCES `table3`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION )");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_table1_mapToTable2_mapToTable3` ON `table1` (`mapToTable2`, `mapToTable3`)");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (`id` INTEGER, `nameOfT2` TEXT, `anotherNameOfT2` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table3` (`id` INTEGER, `nameOfT3` TEXT, `anotherNameOfT3` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
    _db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, '2177a2b52b96e912c0af8db6e8cad3d2')");
  }
```

- as the SQL is written for you. it's just then a matter of creating the ALTER, INSERT AND DROP SQL.

The above compares to the Logged SQL from running the above :-

```
2019-10-12 15:01:34.242 D/ALTERSQL: ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table1_old;
2019-10-12 15:01:34.242 D/CREATESQL: CREATE TABLE table1 (`id` INTEGER , `name` TEXT , `mapToTable2` INTEGER  NOT NULL , `mapToTable3` INTEGER  NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY(`id`),FOREIGN KEY (mapToTable3) REFERENCES `table3`(id)  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,FOREIGN KEY (mapToTable2) REFERENCES `table2`(id)  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
2019-10-12 15:01:34.242 D/INSERTSQL: INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, mapToTable2, mapToTable3) SELECT id, name, mapToTable2, mapToTable3 FROM table1_old;
2019-10-12 15:01:34.242 D/DROPSQL: DROP TABLE table1_old;
2019-10-12 15:01:34.242 D/CREATEINDEXSQL: CREATE  INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_table1_mapToTable2_mapToTable3` ON `table1`(`mapToTable2`,`mapToTable3`);
```

## Disclaimers

The above does not cater for all situations, it is intended solely as a demonstration of the basic techniques. The code does contain some comments as to limitations. However, there are other considerations e.g. partial indexes and the WHERE clause, FTS and the MATCH column for FK's.

Comment: Than'k you so much you help me alot !